# Is it useful to save Year, Month and Date in the Calendar Table

Tags: sql-server, calendar

I am using a calendar table to save day information. My preliminary purpose of the table is to identify working days and leave days (including weekends and holidays). The fields in the table are

- Date (Primary Key)
- Year
- Month
- Day (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc without the suffix)
- Type (Working day, Saturday, Sunday, etc.)

Using the Year, Month and Day fields seemed useful at first especially to set holidays but in hindsight I guess I could have just used `DATEPART(yyyy, [Date])` to get the year and similarly month and day as well. Is there **any** other use in having those fields?

If performance would be a factor how huge would be the impact? The calendar table has data for only 100 years which is ~36,500 records and some leaves can be preset for all the 100 years and a few which fall on different days (~5 records) each year could be setup once every year. Is it even worth it to consider the performance difference?

#### Summary

Is there any use in having seperate fields to save Year, Month and Day information and is the performance difference even big enough to be bothered?

#### Edit 1

From the execution plan, I do not even see any performance difference, so primarily would there be any other use for these fields?

#### Edit 2

Some seem to have misunderstood the question. My question is not how to create the calendar table or opinions about the fields in the calendar table. My question is, is there ***ANY*** use of the `[Year]`, `[Month]` and `[Day]` fields.

Comment: For your sample queries, did you just use `Year` based ones? Because a query based on `DATEPART(year,Date)` should still be able to perform a range query on the index on `Date`. Whereas a `day` based query shouldn't be able to make (effective) use of the index.

Comment: @Daimen, I used Year and Month.

Comment: Once you have the table, it's quite easy to add columns that you need for something, and it's not going to be that big. I think I have (in addition to your fields) also week / month / quarter + year formatted as varchar for easier usage in reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar tables are tiny.  As you pointed out, you are talking about kilobytes for storage to cover 100 years, even if you are storing the year and month explicitly. Row width is not a concern.

If you do keep them, make them computed columns to enforce consistency with `[date]`. If you want them to also physically exist, make them persisted computed columns.

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
  [date] date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ,[year]  AS ISNULL(DATEPART(year,[date]),0)
 ,[month] AS ISNULL(DATEPART(month,[date]),0)
 ,[day]   AS ISNULL(DATEPART(day,[date]),0)
 ,[type] int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)

DECLARE @date_from date = '2000-01-01'
DECLARE @date_to   date = '2099-12-31'

INSERT Calendar ([date])
SELECT TOP(1+DATEDIFF(day,@date_from, @date_to))
  DATEADD(day,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1,@date_from)
FROM master.dbo.spt_values a, master.dbo.spt_values b
```

Comment: That is a brilliant Idea, I was using a loop to populate the table but within the loop I manually computed the Year, Month and Date using `DATEPART` and saved it. Just a 100 years took nearly 20 seconds. When I removed Year, Month and Date it populates 200 years in 1 second. I will try the computed fields and post back if there is any performance difference.

Comment: there was no performance loss when I used computed fields, but does `[Year]` and `[Month]` have any use at all putting aside that they don't take much space, does it have any use at all?

Comment: Having `[year]` and `[month]` fields can make your code plainer and easier to read when you are joining against the table instead of having `DATEPART()` everywhere. The reason to make them computed columns is to ensure consistency with `[date]`. If you want to physically store them, you can use a persisted computed column.

Comment: Thank you @Anon and that is a very neat and sleek example, just curious, why would you use `ISNULL` on `DATEPART`, if `[date]` is the primary key could `DATEPART` some how return a null value?

Comment: SQL Server creates the computed columns as nullable otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through a couple of different iterations of this sort of process and this is how I've implemented it in the past.

Here's a starting point. On each match, stop processing further rules.

- If it is a Saturday, it is a weekend.
- If it is a Sunday, it is a weekend.
- If it is 1 Jan, it is a holiday (New Year's Day).
- If it is 2 Jan and it is a Monday, it is a holiday (New Year's Day Observed).
- If it is the 3rd Monday of January, it is a holiday (MLK Day).
- If it is the 3rd Monday of February, it is a holiday (Presidents' Day).
- If it is the last Monday of May, it is a holiday (Memorial Day).
- If it is 3 Jul and it is a Friday, it is a holiday (Independence Day Observed).
- If it is 4 Jul, it is a holiday (Independence Day).
- If it is 5 Jul and it is a Monday, it is a holiday (Independence Day Observed).
- If it is the 1st Monday of September, it is a holiday (Labor Day).
- If it is the 2nd Monday of October, it is a holiday (Columbus Day).
- If it is 10 Nov and it is a Friday, it is a holiday (Veteran's Day Observed).
- If it is 11 Nov, it is a holiday (Veteran's Day).
- If it is 12 Nov and it is a Monday, it is a holiday (Veteran's Day Observed).
- If it is the 4th Thursday of November, it is a holiday (Thanksgiving Day).
- If it is the 4th Friday of November and it is not 22 Nov, it is a holiday (Black Friday).
- If it is 29 Nov and it is a Friday, it is a holiday (Black Friday).
- If it is 24 Dec and it is a Friday, it is a holiday (Christmas Eve).
- If it is 25 Dec, it is a holiday (Christmas).
- If it is 26 Dec and it is a Monday, it is a holiday (Boxing Day).
- If it is 31 Dec and it is a Friday, it is a holiday (New Year's Eve).
- If none of the above conditions apply, it is a work day.

In this way, you can iterate through the rules and identify work days, weekends, and holidays. You can store these rules using these fields:

- Month
- Day of Month
- Day of Week
- Week Number
- Year

Here is how the algorithm could work.

- If `[Year] > 0`, this rule only affects dates in that year; otherwise, this rule is in effect regardless of year.
- If `[Month] > 0`, this rule only affects dates in that month; otherwise, this rule is in effect regardless of month.
- If `[Day Of Month] > 0 AND [Day of Week] == 0`, this rule affects dates on that day of the month.
- If `[Day of Month] == 0 AND [Day of Week] > 0`, this rule affects dates on that day of the week.
- If `[Day of Month] == 0 AND [Day of Week] > 0 AND [Week Number] > 0 AND [Week Number] < 6`, this rule affects the `[Week Number]` cardinal instance of `[Day of Week]`. For example, if `[Day of Week] = @Monday` and `[Week Number] = 1`, this rule affects the 1st Monday of the month.
- If `[Day of Month] > 0 AND [Day of Week] > 0 AND [Week Number] > 0 AND [Week Number] < 6`, this rule affects the `[Week Number]` cardinal instance of `[Day of Week]` that falls on or after `[Day of Month]`; if `[Week Number]` cardinal instance of `[Day of Week]` falls before `[Day of Month]`, this rule affects `[Week Number] + 1` cardinal instance of `[Day of Week]`. I introduced this to the algorithm for Black Friday.
- If `[Day of Month] == 0` AND `[Day of Week] > 0` AND `[Week Number] == 6`, this rule affects the last instance of `[Day of Week]` during a month.

With this algorithm and these 22 rules, you don't have to store an entry for everything. This will cover all of your U.S. federal holidays for a century. You can add entries for requested leave with exact dates (`[Year]`, `[Month]`, `[Day of Month]`).

Comment: I think the OP is asking about whether the `Month` and `Day` columns should exist, not how to populate the table. Also, of course, there's no guarantee that the OP is based in the US.

Comment: The rules for Federal Holidays change frequently when you are looking at 100-year timespans.  Why try to embed the algorithms in code when you have a fantastically efficient data lookup engine at your fingertips?

Comment: I was guessing US because of Saturday and Sunday. I was showing an algorithm that would forfeit the `[Date]` field and hopefully reduce storage through an algorithm.

Comment: How much storage will that save?

Comment: @PaulRowe, Thank you for the algorithms but my question is whether the fields Year, Month and Day of Month is needed at all. I find them redundant so I wish to know if there is **any** use for them.

Comment: @Lordbalmon If you're storing this information historically and not intending to use rules, there's no need for the `[Year]` and `[Month]` fields. On that point, you probably don't need anything other than `[Date]` and `[Type]`.

Comment: @PaulRowe, I am going to algorithms similar to the ones you have listed however I do not understand why I need to use `[Year]` and `[Month]` when I can just use `DATEPART(MM,[Date])` and `DATEPART(YYYY,[Date])`

Comment: @Lordbalmon Let me clear up some miscommunication. If you have a table storing `[Date]` and `[Type]`, you could use the rules and the `DATEPART` function to identify *why* the `[Date]` was flagged as `[Type]`. You can have your history table that stores `[Date]` and `[Type]` and a rules table that stores the information for your algorithm (which wouldn't include `[Date]`).